How to use git diff for modified files
Im trying to list all lines that have changed in modified files only, for this I'm using the following command
git diff --diff-filter=M

but still, I'm getting changes for new files that have been added to the git repository

This is unexpected behaviour. I just tried it on a minimal repo, only changes for modified files are listed. What's your --version ?

Are all the files staged?

Oh I think my issue is the definition of modified, if I add a new file that file considered modified for some reason by git
